# Keep text centred in an `<li>` when one of the <li> elements contains an <img> and text

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Ive got a simple list like this :

```
<ul>
    <li>ONE</li>
    <li>TWO</li>
    <li>THREE</li>
    <li>FOUR</li>
    <li>FIVE</li>
    <li>SIX</li>

    <li><hr></li>

    <li><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Z/n/k/Z/y/j/left-arrow-gray-hi.png" height="10"> RETURN</li>
</ul>
```

What im trying to do is centre all of the text, which is easily done using `li {text-align: center;}` but ive got an issue with the `<img>` element in the last list item which skews the centre of that list item and makes it out of line with all the others, any idea how i can get round this so that all the text is in a line and the `arrow` sits off the the left of the word RETURN without skewing the centred list.

Ive made a JSFiddle of the problem here : http://jsfiddle.net/rsswou6e/1/

Comment: did u try to set the position of the image as absolute. By doing this its positioning will not affect the text and you can position it however you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some css attributes to move out img from li positioning:

```
li > img {
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not positive if this is what your want - It looks close to centre to me), but you can center the text and image together like this: Put the `img` in a `span`

```
  <li><span><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Z/n/k/Z/y/j/left-arrow-gray-hi.png" height="10"> RETURN</span></li>
```

see the updated Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/rsswou6e/2/